# Error when loading localhost in web browser

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, webserver, raspbian

So I am trying to create a LAMP web server on my raspberry pi and I keep running into an issue were after I have loaded apache2 and php5.

Whenever I load localhost in my web browser I get an error saying:
Oops! It was not possible to show this website

The website at http://localhost/ seems to be unavailable. The precise error was:

Could not connect: Connection refused

It could be temporarily switched off or moved to a new address. Don't forget to check that your internet connection is working correctly.

Now in my /var/www/html file I have index.php file that just has:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

But everytime it loads that page. If I put an index.html file then it works properly. I am still relatively new to php so I feel like I am just doing something incorrectly.

Anyone have any tips on how to fix this issue?

[This is the Worksheet I am following for setup.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/worksheet/)

Comment: have you restarted apache2 after installing php5?

Comment: @ArditMeti yes I have reloaded it, restarted it, removed it, updated it everything.

Comment: So you are saying that with a .html file it works but with .php it doesn't work? In that case check the installation of php5 maybe you had errors installing it?

Comment: @ArditMeti I'll double check but I also installed that and reloaded it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your hosts file :

127.0.0.1       localhost 
::1             localhost